# VBA : How .End(xlup).Row behave on merged ranges (edited)

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Here's the case I'm in right now. I have the following function calls :

```
Call function_1(name_sheet)
Call check_sheet_exist(name_sheet)
Call function_3(name_sheet)
```

This function are called if a condition is true and this condition is in a loop. At the beginning of this loop I have `Workbooks(main).Worksheets(mask_1).Activate`. So the `function_1` is called with this sheet and it does operations on this sheet which is what I want. Then in the `check_name_sheet` function, I'm doing this :

```
Windows(main).Activate
For Each check_sheet In Workbooks(secondary).Sheets
    'some code
Next check_sheet
Workbooks(main).Sheets(mask1).activate '(mask2 can also be activated depending on what parameter is passed)
```

Now that you have the context here comes the problem. In `function_3` I'm trying to do this :

```
Workbooks(secondary).Sheets(name_sheet).Activate 'name_sheet passed as parameters
MsgBox Range("AQ100").End(xlUp).Row
```

The value that I'm waiting for in `Msgbox` is 21 but I'm getting 19. This is because the code searches the last empty line in the sheet `Workbooks(main).Sheets(mask1)`. But I don't know where's the problem because I've specified with the first line the sheet to search to...

I've tried to print every values of variables that I use everything is defined and correct. I also tried this in `function_3` :

```
Msgbox Workbooks(secondary).Sheets(name_sheet).Range("AQ100").End(xlUp).Row
```

`name_sheet` contains the name that the `check_sheet_exist` function did copy so the worksheet obviously is in the workbook. The workbook is open, does exist and the sheet has the correct name.

The only thing I see might be the Windows(main).Activate which is the purpose of my question, does windows.activate denies the change of workbook ?

**EDIT :**

Here's the function where I create the `secondary` workbook :

```
Dim secondary as New Workbook 'outside the function

Sub example ()

Set new_file = Workbooks.Add
With new_file
    .SaveAs Filename:=secondary
End With
secondary = ActiveWorkbook.name

End Sub
```

Here's the main function where the 3 function above are called :

```
For i = 1 To Collection_1.Count
 For j = 1 To 5  
  Workbooks(main).Worksheets(mask_1).Activate
   If Collection_1(i).Length(j) = 5 Then
            Call function_1(name_sheet)
            Call check_sheet_exist(name_sheet)
            Call function_3(name_sheet)
   End If
```

`Function_1` does not modify the active workbook or active sheet.

here's the image of why last row should be 21 :
[image]

Comment: Firstly, the way your code is designed is not the best, at least, in my opinion. Selecting, activating only consumes Excel resources without bringing any benefit and it may promote confusions. For instance, instead of `Workbooks(secondary).Sheets(name_sheet).Activate` followed by `MsgBox Range("AQ100").End(xlUp).Row` it is better to declare `Dim wsSec as Worksheet` `Set wsSec = Workbooks(secondary).Sheets(name_sheet)`, then  `MsgBox wsSec.Range("AQ100").End(xlUp).Row`. I mean to fully qualify the used ranges. Most probably `check_sheet_exist` works on a wrong workbook, if that sheet exists...

Comment: Why don't you share the whole thing (including the functions)? Also, let us know which workbook contains this code.

Comment: That technique for finding the "last line" will only work if column AQ is populated on the last line - without knowing what your data is that could also be a factor

Comment: @FaneDuru True, I read that activate and select were not the best options but I planned to simplify and optimize the code after it works. But check_sheet_exist is running in the correct workbook

Comment: @VBasic2008 The code is very long and not everything is useful for this particular problem. The code is in the "main" workbook. Maybe I should set a variable to have the reference the new workbook. i've edited my question si that you have the function where I initialise the new workbook.

Comment: @CHill60 The AQ column will always be populated when this function execute.

Comment: If you have an `On Error Resume Next` in your code, remove it and don't use it until you fully understand what it does (basically, it ignores errors). The reason why I'm suspecting this is that you cannot select or activate a sheet if its workbook isn't active. If `Workbooks(main)` is active then `Workbooks(secondary).Sheets(name_sheet).Activate` will raise an error.

Comment: I don't have any ```On Error Resume Next``` I'm used to face problem but when I do ```Workbooks(secondary).Sheets(name_sheet).Activate``` I don't get any error...

Comment: Quote: "I planned to simplify and optimize the code after it works." - sometimes doing it the right way first time is what makes it work!
Quote: "The code is very long and not everything is useful for this particular problem." - but what you have shared is not enough for context on this problem. Post the minimum code with sample data for us to reproduce the problem

Comment: @CHill60 Ok I just thought that Questions on SO needed to be short but i'm going to explain all

Comment: In order to obtain the last cell in a column, `Range("AQ100").End(xlUp).Row` is not appropriate. Try using `Range("AQ" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`, Then why declaring `Dim secondary as New Workbook` and not `Dim secondary as Workbook`? If you have `Set new_file = Workbooks.Add`, why using `secondary = ActiveWorkbook.name` instead of `secondary = new_file.name`? Do you like Activation and Active so much? In this piece of code you use `.SaveAs Filename:=secondary`. Does `secondary` contain the workbook full name? And then, do you want changing it using the workbook name (without its path)?

Comment: @FaneDuru For the ```Range```, i'm using ```AQ100``` because the values will never be filled after ```Rows(100)```.  Secondary is not a workbook, it's a string so that I can access this workbook through this string.  ```Secondary``` contains the name I want to assign to this new workbook and to the new file which is for example "Planning_teams.xlsx". I want then change workbook by using this ```secondary``` string variable.

Comment: Using `MsgBox Workbooks(secondary).Sheets(name_sheet).Range("AQ100").End(xlUp).Row` instead of `MsgBox Range("AQ100").End(xlUp).Row`, what does it return? 19 or 21? "Secondary" is obviously as string, but did you carefully read my comment and what I am putting in discussion there? Does it initially contain the full name?

Comment: @FaneDuru The ```Workbooks(secondary).Sheets(name_sheet).Range("AQ100").End(xlUp).Row```
returns 19 because it is in sheet ```mask_1``` and the ```Range("AQ100").End(xlUp).Row ``` returns 15 because it's in mask_2 but I want to have 21 which is the value for the sheet ```name_sheet``` (I see it with my eyes so...). note that ```mask_1 and mask_2``` are in the "main" workbook

Comment: What is 21 in sheet `name_sheet`? Shouldn't it be the last filled row of the respective column? Is it something else? It does not matter where the two sheets are...

Comment: @FaneDuru First of all ty for your help, 21 is the last Row with an empty cell in the AQ column of ```name_sheet``` sheet. 
I also did 2 debug prints right before it looks for the last row :


```MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.name``` which give me the correct filename (workbook) I want to serach in

```MsgBox ActiveSheet.name``` which give me the correct name of the sheet I want to look into "Planning_1"

Comment: Last row = last row with something in it (which should be 20 in your case?), not the "last row with an empty cell", can you share a screenshot of where your lastrow would be (in the sheet with the row numbers to the left), you can hide the other columns for this. There's probably just a misunderstanding here.

Comment: @Notus_Panda I've edited the question so that you have a screenshot. i thought that lastrow would be the last one without something in it but you are saying that it's the last one with information in it

Comment: If you have there a merged cell (you should mentioned that), it returns its top left cell where the value is kept. So, it returns correctly. Your understanding about what it should return is a little not appropriate... Now, what did you mean by "Does Window.activate denies the change of workbook?"? I do not see anything you try changing and you cannot...

Comment: @FaneDuru Yh the question is a bit inappropriate rn because it was only a misunderstanding of Ranges. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine my test sheet:

[image]

Since your problem is having merged cells and have/had a misconception of what the next empty row *after* your lastrow would be:

```
Sub nextEmptyRow()
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print lRow 'gives 9
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & lRow)
    Debug.Print rng.Offset(1).Row 'this is the actual next empty row
    'gives 11
End Sub
```

The offset (tested this to actually know this myself) takes in account the merged cells so it goes 1 further than the last row of the merged cells.

In your case, that'd be:

```
Msgbox Workbooks(secondary).Sheets(name_sheet).Range("AQ100").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
```

Comment: I think i'm the most braindead developper on Earth. Because I've merged Cells, the value that was on ```AH19``` is now in ```Range("AH19:AI20")```. And because of a confusion I though that ```End(xlup).Row``` would give me last row without any value in it which is completly false (and I know it) .So I was expected 21 but the correct ouput is actually 19. i don't know what led me to this confusion but  thanks god I realized "alone". I guess i'm really tired or something because this was stupid. Sorry for the waste of time and thanks for your patience and your help.

Comment: No need to talk down on yourself so much, everyone makes mistakes. You're welcome and hopefully you can catch some sleep soon.

Comment: Yh my bad still but it's funny how code reminds us that even if we're capable of the best sometimes we're capable of the worst.